# How to print the minimum score from 1 array and a name from a different array that corresponds to the other array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print the minimum and maximum number from each array and the name of a student from a different array that corresponds to the number.

This is what I have so far.

import java.util.*;
   import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class Lab5A2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
   meals(console);

}

public static void meals(Scanner console) {
    System.out.print("How many grades ");
    int people = console.nextInt();
    int subtotal = 0;
    int min = 10000;
    int max = 0;
    int avg = 0;
    int[] grades = new int[people];
    for (int i = 1; i <= people; i++) {
        System.out.print("Next grade? ");
        int personCost = console.nextInt();
        subtotal = subtotal + personCost;
        grades[i-1] = personCost;
        if(max <personCost)
        {
          max = personCost;
        }
        if(min>personCost)
          min = personCost;
    }
  String[] names = new String[people];
 System.out.println("Now the names.");
 for (int j = 1; j <= people; j++) {
        System.out.print("Next name? ");
        String name = console.next();

        names[j-1] = name;

  }

    avg = subtotal/people;

    int Min = min;

    int Max = max;
    int Avg = avg;
    int Sum = subtotal;
    System.out.println(Min);
    System.out.println(min);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grades));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));

     int hue = Arrays.binarySearch(grades, Min);
     int huey = Arrays.binarySearch(grades, Max);
  System.out.println(hue);
  System.out.println(huey);

    System.out.println("/*** Statistics from student data ***/");
    System.out.println("Max. Grade = " + grades[huey] + " " + "(" + names[huey] + ")");
    System.out.println("Min. Grade = " + grades[hue] + " " + "(" + names[hue] + ")");
    System.out.println("Avg. Grade = " + Avg);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grades));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
}
}
```

I know I need to use indexes but i just dont know how

Comment: What is the problem? Anyway no sense to do j = 1; j <= people then j - 1. Remove the + from System.out.println("Max. Grade = " + Max +);, System.out.println("Max. Grade = " + Max);

Comment: I got it to print the max properly with the name but for some reason its not able to find 50 in grades array

Comment: I tried your code, and seems like everything works ok..

Comment: I actually got it to work out! I need help with problem 2 now >.<